Probability of coin flip given forecasts
Suppose you have a coin that flips $H$ or $T$ with some unknown probability.
You also have access to two devices, $A$ and $B$, where $A$ correctly predicts the outcome of the coin with $p = 0.7$ and $B$ with $p = 0.6$.
What is the probability $A's$ forecast is correct given $B$ agrees? How about when $B$ disagrees?

I'm curious how we would go about using these tools. How can we
compute the conditional probability of the outcome given that $A$ and
$B$ agree vs disagree. Intuitively, it does not seem possible for $A$
and $B$ to be independent of each other. How could we go about
computing their covariance if this is the case.
If they were to be independent, I would say that the probability of
agreement $= 0.7 \cdot 0.6 + 0.3 \cdot 0.4 = 0.54$ So 54% of the time
you could have some level of confidence in your prediction. I wonder
if we can say this though and am trying to tie in concepts of
conditional probability and correlation.
If we blindly followed tool $A$ we could correctly predict for $70%$
of the coin flips. Can we use $B$ in any way to increase that portion?
To me it seems like we can not as that would involve going against $A$
at some points which seems suboptimal.

EDIT: After thinking about it, I believe A and B can have independent predictions. Let's assume they are if that's true.
(however I'm curious of what would change if we increased correlation. I'm assuming it is not possible for correlation to be 1 as they must be different at some points to have differing proportions. What is max correlation in that case? My intuition tells me the higher the correlation, the less you'd consider the forecast with worse probability.)

Please don't use "EDIT:". Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time. See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Please clarify your question.  masiewpao interpreted the question differently than I did, and I think their interpretation is also reasonable.  This highlights that it's not clear what you are asking.  There appear to be at least 3 questions: what is the probability A is correct if...? what about when B disagrees?  what is the max correlation?  and maybe you want to know whether there is a better decision rule for combining their predictions.

Please pick only one question you want answered.  The rule here is one question per post.  Then, please [edit] your post to clarify which question you want answered, to make it clearer what you are asking, to remove "EDIT:", and make it read well for a first-time reader.  I suggest you also provide context about where the quoted material came from.  Note that you are required to credit the source of all material not originally written by you: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

There isn't enough information to say, because we don't know whether $A$ and $B$'s predictions are independent or not.
If they are independent, then there are two ways for them to agree: they could both be correct, or both be incorrect.  Those have probabilities $0.7 \times 0.6=0.42$ and $0.3 \times 0.4=0.12$.  Therefore the probability that they are correct, given that they agree, is $0.42/(0.42+0.12) = 0.777\cdots$.
But this requires an independence assumption that is not specified in the problem, and might not be valid, so given the information provided, we can't actually know.

(Separately: yes, assuming independence, you can indeed combine the predictions from $A$ and $B$ to get a new prediction rule that is more accurate than $A$ or $B$ alone -- but that is a different question.)

I think the OP is asking a slightly different question (though perhaps not explicitly stated). I.e. when they say "Can we use B in any way to increase that portion?", the question appears to be whether a better strategy than simply following A exists. I suspect in this case the answer is "no", given the OP's own reasoning?

@masiewpao, You might be right.  It's not entirely clear what they are asking.  I invite onlookers to vote to close the question as unclear until it is edited to make it clearer what the question is.
